# how can I append an array value to a string?

Tags: php

I'd like to append an array value to the middle of a string.

I tried making the name as new variable and append the variable. I looked up various ways to grab just one value out of array, but nothing satisfied my needs.

I have this array:

```
$fields = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => '/.+/',
        'message' => $lang['ADMIN_STORE_NAME_VALIDATE'],
        'value' => '',
        'required' => TRUE
    ),
```

I want to append the store name to say, the end of this string

```
sprintf("A cool new store has been added  please login to administrators area to approve the request")
```

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Kind of nonsense, either you _do_ use `sprintf()` or you don't. I would suggest you do, so `sprintf("A cool new store called %s has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request", $fields['name']['message'])`.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question as "not clear": I think it's quite clear indeed.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, I'm not very familiar with sprintf

Comment: @arkascha thank you for the reply, but im still getting "please enter your store name" in place fo where the store name should be . if i removed the [message] part, i get "A cool new store called Array has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request"

Comment: @bsgtesting Where is the name of the store stored? What variable?

Comment: Well, we cannot tell you what value you assign to `$lang['ADMIN_STORE_NAME_VALIDATE']`, that is a totally different question and not part of the code you posted. We can only answer your question which is how to insert the value of that array element into a string. If the element holds another value than you expect, then go and check how it got assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is a concatenation operator.
Therefore, doing something like the following:

```
$sentence = "A cool new store called " . $fields['name']['message'] . " has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request";
```

Is going to give you the result you want.

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: thank you for the reply, but im still getting "please enter your store name" in place fo where the store name should be . if i removed the [message] part, i get "A cool new store called Array has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request"

Comment: Can you tell me where you have your store name stored & how you get to it?

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have a file called en_US.php. inside iit is all these LANG lines. the LANG lines in my code above is the$lang['ADMIN_STORE_NAME_VALIDATE'] 

inside the en_US.php it is assigned the following sentence

$lang['ADMIN_STORE_NAME_VALIDATE'] = "Please enter a Store Name";

Comment: So the actual name of the store is not stored in  $lang['ADMIN_STORE_NAME_VALIDATE']?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can include variable values in the string using directly for simple variable or using `${ }` notation for arrays/objects/etc.  So something like this would work:

```
echo "A cool new store called {$fields['name']['message']} has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request";
```

As noted by @treyBake, for the variable expansion to work, you *must* use double quotes; variables are not expanded in single-quoted strings.

Comment: true^^ though I'd prefer to concat for readability purposes, sometimes you can miss seeing vars inside a string

Comment: Awesome ^.^ removed comment :)

Comment: thank you for the reply, but im still getting "please enter your store name" in place fo where the store name should be . if i removed the [message] part, i get "A cool new store called Array has been added please login to administrators area to approve the request"